# Need a report or count of all users with "Public IM Connectivity" enabled in OCS

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I need to verify that we are still with in our licence limits for public IM connectivity in Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007.  Is there a way to report on which users have the PIC enabled on their account?

I see there are some schema extensions in AD related to other OCS settings, but I do not see one for PIC (unless it is encoded in *msrtcsip-optionflags*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I found the answer to my questions.  The PIC settings are stored in the msrtcsip-optionflags field in Active Directory.  The options are listed [on this page](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/schertz_jeff/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=20), and public IM is option 0x1.

I put together the following Powershell script to get the user count (it uses Quest's snap-in):

```
$users = Get-QADuser -LdapFilter '(msrtcsip-primaryuseraddress=*)' -IncludedProperties "msrtcsip-options" -SizeLimit 0
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $picList = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    if ($user["msrtcsip-optionflags"] % 2 -eq 1)
    {
        $picList.Add($user) |out-null
        $user.Name
    }
}
$picList.Count
```